How do I remove/find dead URLs from my project stored in database?
I'm working on a project where we store millions of endpoints for users (like a user bookmarks a page, a user likes a link and we store it, a user saves favorite endpoint, etc.). We have more than 10-15 million endpoints. We estimate 10-20% of those endpoints are non functional / got removed / moved / dead. How do I remove those URLs from database?
Sometimes the website maybe down temporarily and I don't want to remove it if scripts gives me 404.
What should be my approach ?

There are many ways to tackle the obsolete data deletion problem. Generally speaking you can choose between proactive and reactive approaches.
Proactive
There is a scheduled background job which systematically scans through the links. It fetches a fixed amount of records (like 10 000) and the query utilizes ordering (like creation date). For ordering choose a column which is immutable and has ever growing value
For example

Job run #1: [2021-01-01T00:00:00Z, 2021-01-01T09:17:10Z]
Job run #2: [2021-01-01T09:17:10Z, 2021-01-01T13:42:56Z]
Job run #3: [2021-01-01T13:42:56Z, ...

You have to save somewhere where you are in the systematic scanning so, the next job run can continue where the previous left off.
If you need to handle transient issues (the site is temporarily unavailable) then you can run the jobs on multiple different days to make sure that they are either permanently unavailable or there were some transient failure which is now gone. You can introduce an availability status to capture job runs result for each individual records.
Here is an example for the state transitions:

Once a record is marked for deletion then you can safely remove it.
Reactive
This approach utilizes a reserve proxy between the client and the link which is stored in the database. Whenever someone clicks on a link then the request first hits a reserve proxy which then forwards the request to the actual target. The reserve proxy examines the response and performs the required availability status transition (just like in the batch code). And finally returns the response to the client.
Conclusion
Both approaches have pros and cons. For example the proactive approach scans the links from oldest to newest which could be time consuming to reach up-to-date records. The reactive approach scans only the active links...
It might make sense to combine the two approaches to tackle problem from multiple angles. Whenever you are evaluating which solution to choose please consider the trade offs as well, like the introduced complexity, the added latency to the request processing, etc.
